# How to background a process when tmux prefix is z?

Tags: tmux, background-process

Usually I would background the foreground process using ctrl-z, but when running in tmux with the prefix key bound to z, then obviously ctrl-z just invokes tmux. Likewise if I try to escape the ctrl-z by hitting 'ctrl-z z' then it switches tmux panes (as designed).

Is there another way I can background then foreground process in tmux without having to change the prefix key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your prefix char is `C-z`. The default prefix of `C-b` comes with a default binding of `C-b` (given after the prefix) to the tmux command `send-prefix`. This means you type `C-b` twice to get a real `C-b` sent. You could do the same with `C-z` for example:

```
set-option -g prefix C-z
bind-key C-z send-prefix
```

Now you type `C-z` twice to background the current process.

If your prefix really is `z`, then `C-z` should normally background the current process without the need for a prefix. You can try adding `unbind-key C-z` if it doesn't, or `bind-key C-z send-keys C-z` if you want `zC-z` to do it.

Comment: Yeah, `C-z` is the prefix char. You're right, binding any key to send-prefix does the job. Turns out I had mine set to `v` the whole time with: `bind v send-prefix`.